# Search not efficient after enable flat catalog Products/Categories

Tags: magento-1.9, search

After i enabled flat catalog Products/Categories, search not return appropriate values, sku search completely not working, name search partially working.

> Notes :

```
   am using Ajax search Extensions
```

[image]

Comment: remove cache and reindex once

Comment: bro no use, name search also working partially.

Comment: sku search completely not working,

Comment: select search type as like and combine. and do above suggestion

Comment: ok. goto attributes then goto sku attribute. check there is enable for search results option is yes or not. if no, please make yes and reindex

Comment: bro actually am did what are all the basics, right after also i faced this problem

Comment: have you checked at attributes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45496/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Comment: Not Working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45502/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-teja-bhagavan-kollepara).

Answer (score 0):

in the case flat tables and also for quick search your attribute has below settings to yes.

1) go to `catalog->attributes->manage attributes`

2) find your attribute via name or code

3) go to `frontend properties` and set `Use in Quick Search` to yes

4) reindex the data.

Please do all these steps for all your searchable attributes